# SQL-запрос, который по разному выводит результат в MySQL4 и MySQL5

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте, коллеги.

Помогите разобраться в следующей ситуации. Не знаю, почему один и тот же запрос по разному выводит результат в MySQL 4 и 5.

Запрос:

```
SELECT tab1.id, tab1.name, COUNT( tab2.name ) AS kolvo
FROM tab1
LEFT OUTER JOIN tab2 ON tab1.id = tab2.idTab1
RIGHT OUTER JOIN tab2 tab2_1 ON tab2.id = tab2_1.id
WHERE tab1.isDel <>1
AND tab2_1.isDel <>1
GROUP BY tab1.name, tab1.id
```

результат в MySQL4

```
id | name | kolvo
1 | t1-rec1 | 1
2 | t1-rec2 | 0
3 | t1-rec3 | 0
```

результат в MySQL5

```
id | name | kolvo
1 | t1-rec1 | 1
```

Объясните, почему так происходит или помогите составить корректный запрос, чтобы результат был таким:

```
id | name | kolvo
1 | t1-rec1 | 1
2 | t1-rec2 | 0
3 | t1-rec3 | 0
```

Пример запроса можно посмотреть здесь ([MySQL4](http://svetlanarogozina.ru/tmp/1.php)) и здесь ([MySQL5](http://tex-spassk.ru/tmp/1.php))
Дампы таблиц можно взять [здесь](http://tex-spassk.ru/tmp/1.sql.txt).

Comment: ставь mariadb и забудь про дурацкий мускуль.

Comment: Это такой троллинг или вы серьезно? "Здравствуйте, вот такой код выдает разные результаты в OpenSUSE 10.1 и 11.4. В чем может быть причина?" - "Ставь федору и забудь про дурацкую сузю".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема запроса, как я понял, в том, что `WHERE tab2_1.isDel <>1` срабатывает после остального кода и тем самым отсекает нужные данные. Можно перенести это условие в `JOIN`:

```
SELECT tab1.id, tab1.name, COUNT(tab2.name) 
FROM tab1 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT * from tab2 where tab2.isDel <> 1) tab2 ON tab1.id = tab2.idTab1 
WHERE tab1.isDel <> 1 
GROUP BY tab1.name;
```

UPD.
Комментарий [[@KiTE](/users/2084/kite)](/users/2084/kite) натолкнул:

```
SELECT tab1.id, tab1.name, COUNT(tab2.name) 
FROM tab1 LEFT OUTER JOIN tab2 ON (tab1.id = tab2.idTab1 AND tab2.isDel <> 1) 
WHERE tab1.isDel <> 1 
GROUP BY tab1.name;
```

Comment: Сработало на всех версиях MySQL. Значит только с подзапросом можно решить вопрос? Интересно, почему так 5й мускул реагирует?

Comment: @yozh сработало!

Answer (score 0):

Никак не могу понять логику такого запроса...

Почему не сделать так:

```
SELECT tab1.id, tab1.name, COUNT(*) AS kolvo
FROM tab1
LEFT JOIN tab2 ON tab2.idTab1 = tab1.id
WHERE !tab1.isDel AND !tab2.isDel
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: Задача состоит в том, чтобы подсчитать кол-во записей в таблице tab2 и вывести все строки, которые есть в tab1, а не только те, которые соответствуют строкам в tab2. @KiTE, Ваш пример выводит только одну строку, а необходимо еще и "нулевые" строки вывести.

Comment: Тогда:

    SELECT tab1.id, tab1.name, COUNT(*) AS kolvo
    FROM tab1
    LEFT JOIN tab2 ON (tab2.idTab1 = tab1.id) AND !tab2.isDel
    WHERE !tab1.isDel
    GROUP BY 1

Comment: Не работает! 
id  name  kolvo
1  t1-rec1  1
2  t1-rec2  1
3  t1-rec3  1

Comment: Проблема в `COUNT(*)` -> `COUNT(tab2.name)` - первая считает все совпавшие строки, вторая - все строки без `name`=NULL

Comment: Ага, точно. Хотел упростить. Тогда, как вариант, для лучшей читабельности: `COUNT(tab2.*)`